# iOS Save photo only to custom album using ALAsset

Tags: iphone

as you can only save an image to a custom album, even without saving it on a iPhone camera roll, using the framework `ALAsset`?

Why when I select a photo from the camera roll, to be saved in custom albums, I make a duplicate in the camera roll?

Comment: you can follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954380/save-photos-to-custom-album-in-iphones-photo-library

Comment: Thanks for the link was useful to get an idea.