# Saving photos to custom library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, photo-gallery, alassetslibrary

My problem is really annoying. I'm creating app which takes photos and need to save them to custom gallery. I've found a couple of tutorials how to do this with AlAssetsLibrary but there is one, big problem... There is no `saveImage:toAlbum:withCompletionBlock:` method. I've used `addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:resultBlock:failureBlock:` to create custom photo album but there is no way I can save images to this gallery! I'm using iOS 6 iPhone 4.

Any ideas!?

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/) ?

Comment: Yeah, I saw this earlier but look at my comment under @Vignesh answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you mentioned in the question `saveImage:toAlbum:withCompletionBlock` is not part of [ALAssetsLibrary](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=alassetslibary&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html&ei=Kq3nUbL2E_Lz0gXm3YHgCA&usg=AFQjCNE17Vky3OsDv6jcESIVf1Hu6qB8aw&bvm=bv.49478099,d.d2k). This method is written in [ALAssetLibary's category](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/ALAssetsLibrary_CustomPhotoAlbum.zip?726b5d). You got to import the category in your class to use the method.

To learn more about objective C category , check out the developer [reference](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=objc%20category&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html&ei=063nUeMU6JLRBaKigJAO&usg=AFQjCNGOoqFVX7bVKxpOQ6SLIg2Loik72w&bvm=bv.49478099,d.d2k).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize it is a category... I was searching through the net and tearing my hair out and finally :D

Comment: I have one more question. Is it possible to modify this category not to save this photos to Camera Roll? Only custom album.

Comment: @Cojoj. You are welcome. Its not possible.All image will be stored in camera roll. You can't stop that.

Answer (score 0):

Look at here:

http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/

And there is a Stackoverflow Thread here: [Save Photos to Custom Album in iPhones Photo Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954380/save-photos-to-custom-album-in-iphones-photo-library)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AssetsLibrary you can write this code

```
- (void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;

    if (buttonIndex < 2)    
    {           
        self.library = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
        
        self.imageEditor = [[[DemoImageEditor alloc] initWithNibName:@"DemoImageEditor" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        
        self.imageEditor.doneCallback = ^(UIImage *editedImage, BOOL canceled){

            if(!canceled)
            {
                anotherImage = true;
                
                NSString *imageName;
               
                imageName =@"Abc.jpg";
                
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(editedImage, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);      

                editedImage = [self scaleImage:editedImage toSize:CGSizeMake(600,600)];

                 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(editedImage)forKey:@"image"];

}

- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    UIAlertView *alert;
    
        if (error)

        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                           message:@"Unable to save image to Photo Album." 
                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];

    else 

        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" 
                                           message:@"Image saved to Photo Album." 
                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert release];
}
```

It will solve your case.